# ng-grid is not updating when the scope variable updates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-grid

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong here.  The scope variable which provides data to the grid is being updated, as evidenced by the changing data on the page and console output, however the grid does not refresh.

http://jsbin.com/sicasaqe/1/

I note that this question has been asked before, and there is an issue on github, but none of these examples are as basic as this and the suggestions I tried did not help.

I thought I would post a basic example and see what people think.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the model to your grid this way:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
   data: 'model.data'
};
```

Comment: Ugh, seriously. I am sure I tried that or some variation of it.  It means I also don't need to provide the JSON to the grid, which is something else that puzzled me.

Comment: For posterity, here is an updated and working example.  http://jsbin.com/coraroto/1/